# package org.json does not exist

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, environment-variables, json

I downloaded the JSON library for Java from [Maven Repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160212) and installed the .JAR file at the Java library directory on UBuntu 14.04. I tried compile a simple JAVA snippet for JSON parsing, but the compiler (javac) is telling me that the "org.json" library does not exist..

Here are some details.

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
/usr/share/java

$ ll /usr/share/java/json*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 49176 Jun 12 22:31 /usr/share/java/json-20160212.jar

$ jar tf /usr/share/java/json-20160212.jar 
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/org.json/
META-INF/maven/org.json/json/
META-INF/maven/org.json/json/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/org.json/json/pom.xml
org/
org/json/
org/json/CDL.class
org/json/Cookie.class
org/json/CookieList.class
org/json/HTTP.class
org/json/HTTPTokener.class
org/json/JSONArray.class
org/json/JSONException.class
org/json/JSONML.class
org/json/JSONObject$1.class
org/json/JSONObject$Null.class
org/json/JSONObject.class
org/json/JSONString.class
org/json/JSONStringer.class
org/json/JSONTokener.class
org/json/JSONWriter.class
org/json/Property.class
org/json/XML.class
org/json/XMLTokener.class

$ javac JsonParser.java 
JsonParser.java:1: error: package org.json does not exist
import org.json.*;
^
1 error
```

If I have already set the $CLASSPATH, why the Java Compiler is telling me that the library doesn't exist, when indeed it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling, you must specify the absolute path to the .jar file which contains the package with its classes, like this:

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/json-20160212.jar JsonParser.java
```

According to the official documentation from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) about PATH and CLASSPATH variables:

> The preferred way to specify the class path is by using the -cp command line switch. This allows the CLASSPATH to be set individually for each application without affecting other applications. Setting the CLASSPATH can be tricky and should be performed with care.
>
> The default value of the class path is ".", meaning that only the current directory is searched. Specifying either the CLASSPATH variable or the -cp command line switch overrides this value.